# One-sided nilpotent ideal not in the Jacobson radical?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Problem XVII.5a of Lang's Algebra, revised 3rd edition, is:

> Suppose $N$ is a two-sided nilpotent ideal of a ring $R$. Show that
>   $N$ is contained in the Jacobson radical $J: = \{ \cap\, I: I \text{ a
>  maximal left ideal of } R \}$.

I put my solution below the fold. My question is: can't we generalize a bit more? It seems that all we need is that $N$ is a nil ideal; further, I don't see why $N$ can't be merely a one-sided ideal. I assume there's some error in my thinking here...

---

**Solution:** Take $y \in N$, and show that $1-xy$ has a left inverse for all $x\in R$ (this is an equivalent characterization of the Jacobson radical, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobson_radical#Equivalent_characterizations)). The way to construct the left inverse is to note that $xy \in N$, so $\exists k$ s.t. $(xy)^k= 0$, so $(1 + xy + \dotsb + (xy)^{k-1})(1-xy)=1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is totally correct.

If you require further validation, then check out Lam's *First course in noncommutative rings* pg 53, lemma 4.11 which has exactly the generalization you describe, with the same proof.